# Start and Stop SoundDevice Stream in Different Functions

Tags: python, pyqt, python-sounddevice

I am trying to use sounddevice OutputStream within my PyQt application to play sound.

I want something like

```
import sounddevice as sd

def callback(...):
    #stuff that works with a "with" statement

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        #stuff and buttons

    def startSound(self):
        #called by a button
        self.streamInstance = sd.OutputStream(settings)


    def stopSound(self):
        #called by another button
        self.streamInstance.close()
```

Now this does not work but if I set to have:

```
with sd.OutputStream(settings):
        #a loop
```

It works but I then cannot stop the stream from another function and the app stops running.

If anyone has an idea for a workaround or a fix, it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the error message? Is it similar to https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues/69?

Comment: That's the thing. I do not get an error. It goes through but the callback stream doesn't get called

Comment: There may be a ton of (possibly unrelated) things going wrong ... it might be a simple typo in your code ... it's impossible to say with the given information. You should try to come up with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The stream doesn't start in the initial code sample because you need to explicitly call `streamInstance.start()` on it to start the processing. This is done automatically when you enclose it in a `with` block (as defined within the `_StreamBase` superclass's `__enter__` method).

As Matthias says, it's impossible to tell why you are unable to stop the stream from another function without including more code. If the loop inside your `with` is blocking and you're not using multi-threading, it could be that the other function never gets called.